# How to combine checkbox with jquery Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, datepicker

I want to combine checkbox with jquery Datepicker such that when checkbox is checked, the datepicker should become disable & show predefined date.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "today",
      changeMonth: true, dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd 00:00:00',
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "today",
      changeMonth: true,dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd 00:00:00',
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
  });
```

Once checkbox is checked then -
from = 2000-11-04 00:00:00 & to = today's date.
I am passing these values to HTML Form.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use datepicker method `setDate`(e.g `$( "#from" ).datepicker('setDate', new Date());`

So your code should look something like that:

```
$('#checkbox').change(function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $( "#to" ).datepicker('setDate', new Date()).datepicker( "option", "disabled", true );
        $( "#from" ).datepicker('setDate', new Date(2000, 11, 04)).datepicker( "option", "disabled", true );
   }else{
        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "disabled", false);
        $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "disabled", false);
   }
});
```

Here's [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zxrx5a85/)

Comment: I need to click checkbox twice to make it run. Why is it so?

Comment: I have added jsFiddle to the answer and it's working on first click for me. So probably the problem is somewhere else in the code

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8w8v9/686/)

#### Code

```js
$(function() {

  $('#date').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    altField: '#thealtdate',
    altFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
  });

});

function disableDP() {
  $("#date").attr("disabled", $("#chkDisable").is(":checked")).val("25-11-2015");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Shown Field :
<input id="date" type="text" />
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="chkDisable" onclick="disableDP()">Disable DatePicker
```